# Why is it called an 'integral' curve?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

The concept of a [integral curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve) is relatively easy to understand as path through a vector field which is tangent to the field at each point.

But why is it called an "integral" curve? It appears to have little to do with integers, or integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does somewhat have to do with integration. To find an integral curve, you have to solve a system of ODEs at every point. Let me quote from *John Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, p. 207.

> This
> is the reason for the terminology “integral curves,” because solving a system of
> ODEs is often referred to as “integrating” the system.

Comment: So, when you have these differential equations which define a system, is integration always a fundamental part of their solution? I suppose it probably is. Is this the meaning of "non-integrable" if this can't be done?

Comment: @apkg The standard example of a non-integrable equation is this: Can you find smooth surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$ on which we have $dz-x\,dy = 0$ at each point? (Curves are never a problem, at least locally.)